# Vertical grid lines not showing when using `xticksize`

Tags: pstricks, grids

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-coil,pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \psset{unit=0.6}
  \begin{pspicture}(-2.0,-0.7)(18.2,11.2)
    % x-axis.
    \psaxes[
      yAxis=false,
      xLabels={1997,,,2000,,,,,2005,,,,,2010}
    ]{->}(1,0)(0,0)(15.5,0)[Something,0][,90]
    % y-axis.
    \psaxes[
      xAxis=false
    ](0,0.25)
    \psyTick(0){0}
    \pszigzag[
      coilarm=0.0625,
      coilwidth=0.3,
      coilheight=0.5
    ](0,0.25)(0,0.75)
    \psaxes[
      xAxis=false,
      Oy=10,
      dy=1,
      Dy=2,
      ylabelFactor={\cdot 10^6},
      ticklinestyle=dotted,
      tickwidth=0.5pt,
      xticksize=10 19, % Wrong!
      yticksize=0 15
    ]{->}(0,1)(0,0.75)(0,10.5)[,0][Something else,90]
    \psline[
      linecolor=blue
    ](1,4.55)(2,4.55)(2,4.9)(3,4.9)(3,5.95)(4,5.95)(4,7.35)(6,7.35)(6,8.6)(9,8.6)(9,10)(10,10)
    \rput*(4.5,9){\shortstack[l]{%
      \footnotesize{Antal}\strut\\[-0.5ex]
      \footnotesize{passagerer,}\strut\\[-0.5ex]
      \footnotesize{lufthavnen}\strut\\[-0.5ex]
      \footnotesize{kan betjene}\strut
    }}
    \psline[
      linecolor=red
    ](1,4.3)(2,4.7)(3,5.1)(4,5.5)(5,6)(6,6.45)(7,7)(8,7.55)(9,8.1)(15,9.6)
    \rput*(9,6){\shortstack[l]{%
      \footnotesize{Forventet}\strut\\[-0.5ex]
      \footnotesize{passagertal}\strut
    }}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The vertical lines in the grid are not showing. I am rather sure it is because I have chosen the wrong beginning and end parameters (`10` and `19`) but I have no idea what the correct ones are; any help on this simple question will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the code for `xticksize` to where you build the x axis:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-coil,pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \psset{unit=0.6}
  \begin{pspicture}(-2.0,-0.7)(18.2,11.2)
    % x-axis.
    \psaxes[
      yAxis=false,
      xLabels={1997,,,2000,,,,,2005,,,,,2010},
      ticklinestyle=dotted,
      tickwidth=0.5pt,
      xticksize=0 10,
    ]{->}(1,0)(0,0)(15.5,0)[Something,0][,90]
    % y-axis.
    \psaxes[
      xAxis=false
    ](0,0.25)
    \psyTick(0){0}
    \pszigzag[
      coilarm=0.0625,
      coilwidth=0.3,
      coilheight=0.5
    ](0,0.25)(0,0.75)
    \psaxes[
      xAxis=false,
      Oy=10,
      dy=1,
      Dy=2,
      ylabelFactor={\cdot 10^6},
      ticklinestyle=dotted,
      tickwidth=0.5pt,
      yticksize=0 15
    ]{->}(0,1)(0,0.75)(0,10.5)[,0][Something else,90]
    \psline[
      linecolor=blue
    ](1,4.55)(2,4.55)(2,4.9)(3,4.9)(3,5.95)(4,5.95)(4,7.35)(6,7.35)(6,8.6)(9,8.6)(9,10)(10,10)
    \rput*(4.5,9){\shortstack[l]{%
      \footnotesize{Antal}\strut\\[-0.5ex]
      \footnotesize{passagerer,}\strut\\[-0.5ex]
      \footnotesize{lufthavnen}\strut\\[-0.5ex]
      \footnotesize{kan betjene}\strut
    }}
    \psline[
      linecolor=red
    ](1,4.3)(2,4.7)(3,5.1)(4,5.5)(5,6)(6,6.45)(7,7)(8,7.55)(9,8.1)(15,9.6)
    \rput*(9,6){\shortstack[l]{%
      \footnotesize{Forventet}\strut\\[-0.5ex]
      \footnotesize{passagertal}\strut
    }}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SvendTveskæg You're welcome!